# Committing Idle in transaction query from backend

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.1

I found in `pg_stat_activity`, a query that is currently `<IDLE> in transaction`.

If I call `pg_cancel_backend` on this query's `procpid`, the transaction will be rolled back. Am I right?

How can I issue a `commit` command to the transaction from my DB console?

Is there a `pg_commit_backend(procpid)` or something similar?

The reason wanting to commit is, I can't trace where this query is from, and it's probably from a buggy code. However, I can't afford to roll back as this will result in the loss of what was done in the transaction before it became idle. It will be useful to commit from backend so the query can release its locks, and other waiting queries can proceed.

Comment: I don't yet have an account in DBA SE. I normally ask questions about database in SO. This is the first time I got a migrate vote.

Comment: It has to be assumed that a half-finished transaction may contain incoherent data. Forcing a commit without the client knowing it goes against the concept of transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't commit a transaction from outside the running backend. You need to track down and fix the buggy code. There's no way to force a commit from outside the running session.

You are correct that `pg_terminate_backend` will roll the transaction back. Similarly, `pg_cancel_backend` will cancel a running query and in the process roll the transaction back.

If you don't know what a transaction has done or what stage it's up to it'd be wrong to commit it anyway. You don't know if it's half-way through some work, even if it's been idle for some time.

OK, if you were really desperate, you could probably use `gdb` to inject a `commit` command by attaching to the backend with a debugger. That's risky and really a one-off act of desperation, it's not remotely sane to do routinely or automatically, and it's not appropriate for your situation where it seems your code is routinely leaving idle-in-transaction sessions.

Do you log all your queries with a useful `log_line_prefix`? If so you can reconstruct them from the logs.

Another option of desparation is to use `pg_dirtyread` or a similar tool to read the uncommitted / rolled-back data. You'll *also* see deleted data, data that's the old version of `update`d rows, etc, so there's a bunch of sorting-through to do.

Comment: @ADTC Hopefully your applications are designed so they keep the information until they get a confirmed commit.  If not, see edit - you can if it's really important possibly recover the data from the heap by overriding MVCC and doing a dirty read of the table using add-on tools.

Comment: That's good to know. Anyway we decided to terminate the transactions and move on.